# Django: What is the first method that is called in by as_view() in form views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a URL conf as `/book/(?P<book_id>\d+)/(?P<page_id>\d+)/edit/` where`django.views.generic.edit.FormView` as handler to this endpoint.

As soon as the request is made, I have to check whether there is a `Book` object is present with `book_id` and the page number is present in respective `Book` using `page_id`.

Where exactly would be the appropriate place to do this processing? I would also like to store them as instance attributes for further processing wherever required.

**Edit**

Also, the tricky part here is that the `form_class` used here is totally dependent on the objects found!

Currently in our function based views, a decorator is used to the method which does the job. In class based views, I am not sure what's the place to do it.

In typical function base view

```
def get_object_or_404(view_function):
    def decorator(request, book_id, page_id):
        return view_function(request, book, page)
    return decorator

@get_book_or_404
def edit_book(self, book, page):
    # process the page
    return HttpResponse()
```

I am basically figuring out the simple approach equivalent of `get_book_or_404` for class based views

Comment: Sounds like you need this checking logic in your own view, rather than just wiring that URL to FormView.  But why do you need to check?  Doesn't FormView result in a 404 if <book_id> or <page_id> doesn't exist?

Comment: Do you want the form to validate if your criteria are not met or do you want to redirect or something else? You can have a look here to see what methods you can overwrite in your `Form`: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

Comment: @FrobberOfBits I am not clear what you have said. Actually the `SingleObjectMixins` provide methods to automatically find object based on `pk` argument in URLConf. However, I can't use it here since there are two models! and the actual `self.object` (taken from `page_id`) is only retrieved based on `Book` object using `book_id`

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I haven't gone until the form validation. Please refer to the updated question. I want to first verify the criteria and then do something else!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, and you shouldn't care, what is the first method called in the view. The point is to put logic where it belongs. In this case, since you're concerned with getting instances, you should probably override `get_object`. In that method you can return the `book` object, but also store both book and page objects as instance attributes.